# ASUS PB238Q Yellow tint

Tags: display, display-settings, monitor-settings

I bought the said monitor around 5 weeks ago and have been using it with a blue rigger DVI cable with no problems.

Anyway, tonight I got in from work and used the PC for around an hour, everything normal. I then turned off and later on turned back on again.

This time around I am greeted by a yellow tint to everything being displayed.

**Method of elimination.**

1.) Swapped the said DVI cable with a brand new DVI cable that came with the monitor - **STILL YELLOW**

2.) Swapped the new DVI cable with a HDMI cable on a HDMI port - **STILL YELLOW**

3.) Unplugged the monitor from my PC, plugged a laptop into it via HDMI - **ALSO YELLOW**

At this point I feel I have established that the GPU is not the issue, nor the cables, so I unplug the power cable and re-plug, the monitor turns back on again and is still yellow.

I go into calibrate colour and follow the wizard, at the colour setting I am able to make the monitor have a red tint and green tint, but cant the colour normal.

I now press the menu button on the monitor. The menu pops up and the colour on that seems normal. I navigate to 'System Setup' and select 'Splendid Demo' and set this to 'ON' then low and behold half of the screen goes back to normal with a hovering title 'Splendid Off' over it whilst the other half has the yellow tint still and the title 'Splendid On'.

I cannot work out why splendid is on, or how I turned it on or how I turn it off, I believe this is the issue as the comparison of being on or off shows the yellow and normal. Can anyone tell me what to do to remove this?

Comment: Try booting off of some kind of linux live USB to make sure it's not some kind of software issue first - Otherwise you may be looking at a bad connector or something else like that on the monitor's end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these two settings from the menu button:

1. Color -> Skin Tone -> Natural (there seems to be a "Yellowish" option there!)
2. System Setup -> All Reset -> Yes

Usually monitors have pre-set modes similar to your "Splendid" option that varies just the intensity and contrast. It appears that your "Splendid" mode must be in one that is also is changing the hues and colors.

The descriptions of the various Splendid modes is [described here.](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/405708/Asus-Pb238q.html?page=17#manual)

Comment: In Colour > Colour Temp, the blue was set to Zero but everything else 100%. I have no idea how this has happened but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: UPDATE: Turned on the pc this morning and the yellow tint was back, went to colour settings and the Blue was back down to ZERO. Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Proposed "works for me" solution I've read on some forum postings: Simply uninstall the "ASUS Splendid Video Enhancement" application and the problem ~goes away~